# SQL/Oracle - "Cannot insert null into primary key"

Tags: sql, oracle, null, primary-key, oracle-apex

So, I have an Oracle database (in APEX) in which I have a column called "Scheme".

Like seen below:

```
CREATE TABLE Scheme
  (
Scheme_ID    NUMBER NOT Null,
description VARCHAR2 (800) ,
price FLOAT (3) ,
amount_sold     INTEGER ,
Personal_Trainer_ID NUMBER NOT NULL
) ;
ALTER TABLE Schema ADD CONSTRAINT Schema_PK PRIMARY KEY ( Schema_ID ) ;
```

Now, all my tables are set-up like this and perfectly working, but when I try an insert on my Scheme, it says I'm trying to insert null into the primary key scheme_ID.

I'll show you 2 SQL inserts I use. One for a personal_trainer, and one for the Scheme.

```
INSERT INTO Personal_Trainer (name, loginname, date_of_birth, password)
VALUES('Bojan', 'Bojan', '15-07-1974','fitline');
```

Peronal_Trainer has a Personal_Trainer_ID as primary key, exactly set-up like the Scheme. Inserting this command works perfectly fine.

```
insert into schema (description, price, amount_sold, Personal_Trainer_ID)
values ('3x pushups, 5x bench, 7x squats - 15kg',200, 1, 2);
```

Now, when I try to insert this command I get this error message:

ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEME"."SCHEME_ID")

****************************EDIT*****************************************

```
CREATE TABLE Personal_Trainer
(
Personal_Trainer_ID NUMBER  NOT NULL,
name                VARCHAR2 (35) ,
date_of_birth       DATE ,
loginname           VARCHAR2 (35) ,
password            VARCHAR2 (35)
) ;
ALTER TABLE Personal_Trainer ADD CONSTRAINT Personal_Trainer_PK PRIMARY KEY     ( Personal_Trainer_ID ) ;
```

This is my table of Personal Trainer.

Comment: 'Sheme_ID' is a 'NOT NULL' field but it is not in your insert statement.

Comment: Thats my Personal_Trainer table, it's also NUMBER NOT NULL but yet i do not have to insert a personal_trainer_ID, it should be AUTO_INCREMENT, but when I use this line, I get another error message.

Comment: can you show me some data of the table personal_trainer

Comment: @Ivaro18 Try to keep your code in the question rather than as a comment.

Comment: Edited. I shall delete the comment

Comment: Please check the name of your table. You create the table "scheme" and alter table "schema". Does there exist any insert triggers on table Personal_Trainer? Probably the field Personal_Trainer_ID is set in a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I found it, the NOT NULL constraint still works fine, but my Column is actually called 'Schema' (other language) and apparently this has a definition in Oracle. So it's never altered as a primary key. Changing the table his name should work.

Thanks for the fast responds and help!

**DONT USE RESERVED TERMS FOR YOUR TABLE NAMES!**

Answer (score 5):

You need to provide a unique, not null, value for `schemeid`.

Oracle 12c allows you to elegantly define this column as an identity column:

```
CREATE TABLE Scheme
(
    Scheme_ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
    description VARCHAR2 (800) ,
    price FLOAT (3) ,
    amount_sold INTEGER ,
    Personal_Trainer_ID NUMBER NOT NULL
);
```

In earlier Oracle versions this option isn't available, unfortunately. The idiomatic solution would be to declare a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE scheme_id_seq;
```

And either use it directly:

```
INSERT INTO schema 
(scheme_id, description, price, amount_sold, Personal_Trainer_ID)
VALUES 
(scheme_id_seq.nextval, '3x pushups, 5x bench, 7x squats - 15kg',200, 1, 2);
```

Or create a trigger to fill it in automatically:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER schema_insert_tr
BEFORE INSERT ON schema
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :new.scheme_id IS NULL THEN
        SELECT scheme_id_seq.nextval INTO :new.scheme_id FROM DUAL;
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

because `Scheme_ID` is primary key and not null,

to solve it everytime you insert a record you should insert value for `Scheme_ID` or remove it from pk and make it null

As for personal_trainer, are you sure personal_trainer_id is primary key ? because its impossible to insert null into primary key

Comment: But I need a Scheme_ID as primary key, inserting it everytime is not enduser-friendly so I don't think that's a good idea :/

Answer (score 0):

Primary key has not null constraint, therefore you have to insert some value in the primary key for the insertion to work.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle don't have auto_increment columns.
Instead you need to create sequence like
`CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_SCHEME_ID`
and then use
`insert into schema (Scheme_ID,description, price, amount_sold, Personal_Trainer_ID)
values (SEQ_SCHEME_ID.nextval,'3x pushups, 5x bench, 7x squats - 15kg',200, 1, 2);`

You may put sequence logic in "before insert for each row" trigger. 
In such case you may insert row without mentioning primary key column.
It will be filled in with the sequence.nextval value automatically by trigger.
This is the case of Personal_Trainer table.
You may find this trigger and create similar one for SCHEMA table.